# Batch Cooking Meatballs

Tags: freezing, meatballs

I'm after batch cooking mini meatballs in sauce for my kids, so I'm wondering how best to prepare the meatballs so they can be frozen and reheated? I'm assuming it wouldn't be good to soak the breadcrumbs in milk? But I'm very much a beginner so not sure how best to go about it. Thanks :)

Comment: I usually partially cook my meatballs on a plate in microwave. That makes them tough enough to fly around in a pan without deforming. I've never frozen before the finishing conventional cook, but they certainly seem sturdy enough to freeze easily.

Comment: It's kind of a broad question. Is there any specific part about which you're curious? Since you didn't accept the given answer, I'm guessing that you're looking for different info. I cooked at a pretty upscale Italian restaurant where we used to batch-cook meatballs and freeze them, so if you had any more specific questions, I'm sure that I or someone else could answer them.

Answer (score 2):

Meatballs can be pre-formed, frozen, then cooked....or cooked then frozen, then reheated with minimal if any loss of flavor.  Soaking breadcrumbs (or not) is irrelevant.  If it were me, I would form, cook in sauce, portion, freeze, reheat when ready.

Answer (score 0):

to shape little meatballs, get a small scoop -- like an ice cream scoop only smaller.  much easier than shaping by hand.

I'd cook them first and then freeze them.  they'll stick together better and freeze in a single layer on a cookie sheet and then transfer to a plastic bag.  they you can take out as many as you need for dinner.